# jQuery 1.4.4+ AJAX request - post empty array or object becomes string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

I have a object in Javascript that I am trying to AJAX POST to a PHP script. Everything worked in jQuery 1.4.1 but now in 1.4.4 or above all empty arrays or empty objects arrive as a string(0) which is incorrect.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var obj = {};
obj.one = [];
obj.two = {};
obj.three = [];
obj.three.push('one');
obj.three.push('two');
obj.three.push('three');
obj.four = "onetwothree";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: obj,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
});
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
array(4) {
  ["one"]=> string(0) ""
  ["two"]=> string(0) ""
  ["three"]=> array(3) {
    [0]=> string(3) "one"
    [1]=> string(3) "two"
    [2]=> string(5) "three"
  }
  ["four"]=> string(11) "onetwothree"
}
```

In version 1.4.1 it would just NOT send ["one"] or ["two"], but now in the newer versions, the fact that it arrives as a string throws off the whole application. Is there anything I can do so that an empty array ([]) arrives in PHP as an empty array ([]) and same with JavaScript objects?

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution to this problem? I am also interested in this. Before I saw your post I already posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179473/why-jquery-ajax-does-not-serialize-my-object).

Answer (score 3):

try applying JSON.stringify to the parameters passed

```
 data: JSON.stringify ( obj ),
```

Note you'll likely want to include the `contentType: "application/json"` option to prompt server side to process the data correctly.

quoting : [Why jQuery ajax does not serialize my object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179473/why-jquery-ajax-does-not-serialize-my-object)

> traditional: true is completely wrong, since it can never handle object hierarchies. What you get instead is: ...&key=[object Object], which is javascript's toString() default result for all objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `traditional` option to `true`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: obj,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Have a look at the `data` and `traditional` options of the [newer API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

And remove the extra comma from after the `success` callback if you want things to work in IE7.

Comment: Thank you Karim79, I tried switching the traditional to true but the empty array and object still came across as a string(0) but now my nested array became [object Object].