# Why jQuery ajax does not serialize my object?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I am using jQuery 1.7.1. and I have the following question/problem:

The code has as follows:

```
var accountObject = new Object();
accountObject.account = new Object();
accountObject.account.sas = [];

$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/a/2",
    data: accountObject,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert_user("Successfully saved the selected session attributes as defaults");
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        alert_user(msg);            
    }
});
```

The problem is that, due to the fact that I set `accountObject.account.sas` to an empty array, the `data` arrives completely empty at the server, as:

{}

where it should have been:

```
{ "account": { "sas": [] } }
```

When I put some entries in the `sas` property of `account` then everything is ok. For example, if I put the string "1", "2" and "3" as an array `["1", "2", "3"]` then I get on the server:

```
{ "account": { "sas": [ "1", "2", "3" ] } }
```

Does anybody know why this is so?

Thanks in advance
Panayotis

Comment: `dataType: "html",` ? Try `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @JoeTuskan: the `dataType` is only responsible and needed for the returned data.

Comment: `dataType` is irrelevant; that controls the expected response format, not the format of the query parameters.

Comment: How are you receiving the data on the server-side? from the request body? POST scope? URL scope?

Comment: @KevinB I am processing the request using Ruby on Rails. ```params[:account][:sas]``` should either give me an array with elements or without. But if I send empty array, ```params[:account]```  is not present at all. Please, note also, that when I were in jQuery 1.4.4 it was sending an empty string ```""``` for ```parasm[:account][:sas]```, as it is also described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319106/jquery-1-4-4-ajax-request-post-empty-array-or-object-becomes-string/5319127#5319127). Probably my post I can now say that it is a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that an empty array cannot be properly represented in a query string. When you pass the object hierarchy to `data`, jQuery will attempt to convert it to a query string, but can't figure out what to do with an empty array.

The reason why 1.4.4 seemed to return an empty string whenever it got passed the same hierarchy was that it attempted to pass the key to the query string without a value,  the  result of which would be like: `...&property=&`. This is by default interpreted as an empty string in most server environments.

I personally consider the behavior of 1.7.1 correct, because it forces the developer to check for parameter existence instead of mucking the type of the parameter.

---

**Some notes about various things mentioned here**

- `traditional: true` is completely wrong, since it can never handle object hierarchies. What you get instead is: `...&key=[object Object]`, which is javascript's `toString()` default result for all objects.
- `JSON.stringify` assigned to `data` will result in the entire thing passed as JSON to the query string, unless you combine it with `processData: false`, in which case you need to deserialize into meaningful objects "by hand" on the server side. It's generally a useful option, but overkill in this case where a simple check would presumably have things working with minimal hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the empty array. You can either send an empty string or according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319127/168097) you try setting `traditional: true`

there is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6761524/168097) answer, which apaart from `traditional` also suggests using `JSON.stringify`. In the comments they also mention aps.net mvc model binder being the issue.

I don't how ruby achieves the equivalent of asp.net mvc's model binding, but I think this is where you should look.

Comment: I do not want to send an empty string. I want to send an empty array. So that I can treat the request on server uniformly. I have tried ```tranditional: true``` but it does not work as expected. Also, the answer on the post you direct me to is not accepted.